# Changing the shape of a tensorflow variable in a checkpoint

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a pretrained model (checkpoint, tensorflow v1) with different variables and weights. I don't know all the variables, but I know two that I want to change their shape: v1 is in the shape of [4,768] and v2 is in the shape of [4]. I want to increase both to be [5,768] and [5] respectively and save the checkpoint again for fine-tuning purposes. To fill the missing data I want to take the average values of the variables.

Here is my code:

```
# The vars I want to change
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[4, 768], initializer=utils.classification_initializer())

v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[4], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

checkpoint = {}
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:

 # Restore checkpoint from source location (path).
 saver.restore(sess, source)

 # Get the vars values
 checkpoint[v1.name] = v1.eval()
 checkpoint[v2.name] = v2.eval()

 new_data = {}
 # Calc v1 average and reshape
 avg = numpy.average(checkpoint[v1.name], axis=0)
 new_data[v1.name] = numpy.vstack((checkpoint[v1.name], avg))

 # Calc v2 average and reshape
 avg = numpy.average(checkpoint[v2.name], axis=0)
 new_data[v2.name] = numpy.append(checkpoint[v2.name], avg)

 # Assign the new data and shape
 sess.run(tf.assign(v1, new_data[v1.name], validate_shape=False))
 sess.run(tf.assign(v2, new_data[v2.name], validate_shape=False))

 # Save the checkpoint to target location (path).
 saver.save(sess, target)
```

I was expecting to see a similar size model (the source checkpoint is about 1GB), but i get a much smaller file (target checkpoint is about 15KB). It seems that is saves only the variables that I've changed and not the entire checkpoint (other vars, weights, etc).

1 - this is the way to achieve my goal (reshaping and filling 2 vars in a checkpoint)?

2 - if so, how can i save the entire model (other vars, weights, etc) and not only the loaded vars?

**Update**

The model was originally trained (by someone else) on a TPU machine. Therefore loading the meta graph is not working on a GPU machine (my machine).
However, using the tf.estimator.tpu.TPUEstimator I can train and predict this model. Therefore the TPUEstimator has a way to load everything, change the vars and save the model.

The model: https://storage.googleapis.com/tapas_models/2020_10_07/tapas_wikisql_sqa_inter_masklm_base_reset.zip

Example vars to change: output_weights_agg is a [4, 768], output_bias_agg is [4].

Full code example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yoyZ-45So5pEIGmZp85ut38lW653KHXL?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your code, There are only two variables(v1 and v2) in your graph, then the saver would only restore them from checkpoint.
You can import graph from checkpoint first and do what you want to do then.

Sample code from yours, tensorflow version==1.15.0

```
checkpoint = {}
# import graph from checkoutpoint meta like "/tmp/model.ckpt.meta"
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("path of meta")

with tf.Session() as sess:

 # Restore checkpoint from source location (path) like "/tmp/model.ckpt".
 saver.restore(sess, source)

 # print(tf.global_variables())
 # you can get the name of variable from graph through tf.global_variables()
 v1 = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name == "v1:0"][0]
 v2 = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name == "v2:0"][0]

 # Get the vars values
 checkpoint[v1.name] = v1.eval()
 checkpoint[v2.name] = v2.eval()

 new_data = {}
 # Calc v1 average and reshape
 avg = numpy.average(checkpoint[v1.name], axis=0)
 new_data[v1.name] = numpy.vstack((checkpoint[v1.name], avg))

 # Calc v2 average and reshape
 avg = numpy.average(checkpoint[v2.name], axis=0)
 new_data[v2.name] = numpy.append(checkpoint[v2.name], avg)

 # Assign the new data and shape
 sess.run(tf.assign(v1, new_data[v1.name], validate_shape=False))
 sess.run(tf.assign(v2, new_data[v2.name], validate_shape=False))

 # Save the checkpoint to target location (path).
 saver.save(sess, target)
```

**update**

a workaround: print all tensors from checkpoints, get their names and shapes,then use tf.get_variable to build variable in graph.

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file

# List ALL tensors 
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name=checkpoint_path, tensor_name='', all_tensors=True)
```

**Alternative method:**

```
# List ALL tensors
vars_list = tf.train.list_variables(checkpoint_path)
print(vars_list)
```

**PS:** When import graph from meta data comes from other platforms, we may need to build graph ourselves, and the relations between nodes could be found from graph_def

```
tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when I try to use the import_meta_graph and then restore, i get an error: "Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. ... No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'TPUReplicatedInput' used by node input0" - it seems like this method is coupled to specific hardware? (i run the model on a GPU machine while it seems that it was trained on a TPU machine)

Comment: When i set "clear devices" i still get "No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'InfeedEnqueueTuple'"...

Comment: @Omri I see, how about printing all tensors in checkpoints? you can know their names and shapes. then use tf.get_variable like you do it before

Comment: @FancyXum but what about other meta data? it wont be lost? somehow when i use tf.estimator.tpu.TPUEstimator it knows how to fallback to the GPU and worked, but i could not find how it loads the model...

Comment: Moreover, when i try to load all vars (634 vars) i get another error "global_step; expected dtype float does not equal original dtype int64".

Comment: @Omri The key problem is that the tensorflow used to build the graph comes from TPU, so the corresponding OP kernel cannot be found on other platforms like cpu or gpu. We will lose the relationship between each node if we only get vars, maybe we need to build the graph through meta data.

Comment: When import meta graph, how about tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node to get nodes infomation

Comment: I get all the problems (also edited the question to be clear), but how the tf.estimator.tpu.TPUEstimator works and be able to train and predict with the model on a GPU machine? so there is a way to load everything...

Comment: FancyXum, I didn't solve it yet. however I think you deserve the bounty for providing helpful answer